# Create a list of Buttons using AdaptativeCard that behaves like CardAction?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have the following requirements on my RootDialog:
1) Present the user with a set of choices;
2) But at the same time, let the user free to ask me anything, even unrelated to the options presented, and forward it to QnAMaker;

To fit the first requirement I've first tryed this

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
     PromptDialog.Choice(context, OnOptionSelected, options, "Sobre o que você deseja falar ?", "Você deve escolher entre uma das opções a seguir");
}
```

In this case the OnOptionSelected method was called succesfully. Great :)

But then when I've tried to archeive the second requirement I've realized that the "Prompt.Choice" strategy wasn't a good option, cause it stoped calling my "MessageReceivedAsync" method if the user typed somithing diferent from the choices that prompt.
In this case I've become unable to handle the text free-typed by the user because

```
PromptDialog.Choice(context, OnOptionSelected, options, "Sobre o que você deseja falar ?", "Você deve escolher entre uma das opções a seguir");
```

Have created its own dialog on the top of the dialog stack, preventing my RootDialog to handle the text typed by the user;

Then I've had the briliant idea to replace the "PromptDialog.Choice" to an AdaptativeCard to render the buttons with the options I want but without changing my dialog stack, so if the user type something completly diferent of the options I've presented to him, I'll be able to forward it to Q&A Maker.

To create my AdaptativeCard I've used a SubmitAction like bellow:

```
card.Actions.Add(new SubmitAction
                {
                    Title = option,
                    Data = option
                });
```

But the problem is that when the user click the SubmitAction (rendered as a button on the emulator) the text of the button the user has clicked doen't appers on the conversation, despide of being sucessfuly posted to my MessageReceivedAsync method.
Is there any way I can create a list of buttons using AdaptativeCard that behaves like CardAction used on VideoCard.Buttons ? I mean a card that when you click on it, you can see it's text like a TextBlock on the oposite side of  the button ?

Comment: Why an adaptive card and not just a hero card with buttons? Also, using a promptchoice is doable, but you need to inherit from it to customize it; have you consider that approach?

Comment: HeroCard work well for me thanks for the tip. However, do you have any example of inheriting PromptDialog.Choice  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in the comments, I believe that for what you would like to achieve, a `HeroCard` with `ImBack` buttons type will be just enough. You can check the [cards-RichCards](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards) sample to learn more about the different type of cards.

Regarding how to create a custom `PromptChoice` by inheriting, you can check the [CancelablePromptChoice](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers.BotAssets/Dialogs/CancelablePromptChoice.cs). Basically, you need to override the `TryParse` and add your custom logic, to either pass-through any response you receive or just the ones you want. In the one that I'm linking, the customization was done to accept terms to quit from the `PromptChoice`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ejadib I've just replaced the PromptDialog.Choice with a HeroCard and it fitted my requirements like a charm.

```
//This returns a new new HeroCard with some buttons inside of it
var rootCard = GetCard();

var reply = context.MakeMessage();
reply.Attachments.Add(rootCard);

await context.PostAsync(reply);
context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
```

Follows may RootDialog implementation:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        //private static IEnumerable<string> options = new List<string> { GlobalResources.AboutToro, GlobalResources.Investiments, GlobalResources.IsThereAnyRisk, GlobalResources.ResourceDeposits, GlobalResources.Access_LoginAndPasswords, GlobalResources.AccountOpening };
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            var message = await result;

            if (message.Text == null || message.Text.Equals(GlobalResources.Back, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {   //Quando entra nesse diálogo a 1ª vez ou volta de um dialogo filho.
                var rootCard = GetCard();

                var reply = context.MakeMessage();
                reply.Attachments.Add(rootCard);

                await context.PostAsync(reply);
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
            else if (message.Text.Equals(GlobalResources.AboutToro, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                context.Call(new AboutToroDialog(), OnResumeToRootDialog);
            }
            else
            {
                var messageToForward = await result;
                await context.Forward(new QnADialog(), AfterFAQDialog, messageToForward, CancellationToken.None);
                return;
            }
        }

        private async Task AfterFAQDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            //var messageHandled = await result;
            //if ((bool)messageHandled == true)
            //{
            //    await context.PostAsync("Sorry, I wasn't sure what you wanted.");
            //}

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        private async Task OnResumeToRootDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            await MessageReceivedAsync(context, result);
        }

        private Attachment GetCard()
        {
            var buttons = new List<CardAction>
            {
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = GlobalResources.AboutToro,
                    Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
                    Value = GlobalResources.AboutToro
                },
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = GlobalResources.IsThereAnyRisk,
                    Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
                    Value = GlobalResources.IsThereAnyRisk
                },
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = GlobalResources.ResourceDeposits,
                    Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
                    Value = GlobalResources.ResourceDeposits
                },
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = GlobalResources.Access_LoginAndPasswords,
                    Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
                    Value = GlobalResources.Access_LoginAndPasswords
                },
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = GlobalResources.AccountOpening,
                    Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
                    Value = GlobalResources.AccountOpening
                },
            };

            var images = new List<CardImage>
            {
                new CardImage("http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple117/v4/b8/d5/5e/b8d55e77-d70e-f22b-17b7-2498d974a4fe/source/175x175bb.jpg")
            };

            return new HeroCard("Em que posso te ajudar ?", "subtitle", "bla bla bla",images, buttons).ToAttachment();
        }

    }
}
```